# Javascript: restarting countdown timer doesn't work as I expect it to

Tags: javascript, timer

I am making a countdown timer that should be reseting and starting anew every 10 seconds.
This is the code I came up with by now:

```
function count(){
    var end_date = new Date().getTime()+10*1000;
    setInterval(function(){
      var current_date = new Date().getTime();
      var seconds_left = parseInt((end_date - current_date) / 1000);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = seconds_left + " seconds ";
    }, 1000);
}

setInterval(function(){count()}, 10*1000);
```

It is supposed to function as follows:
+ I set interval that will restart *count()* every 10 seconds.
+ *count()* defines **end_date** - a date 10 seconds from now.
+ then *count()* sets interval that will restart every 1 second.
+ every 1 second **seconds_left** variable is changed according to how **current_date** changed with respect to **end_date**.
+ as soon as **seconds_left** becomes 0, setInterval from step 1 fires and starts *count()* anew.

Which step am I implementing the wrong way? Do I misunderstand the functioning of *setInterval()*?
Here is my JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sy5stjun/ .

Comment: Are you expecting ```setInterval``` (the one in ```count```) to stop calling the function at some time? There is nothing in your code to make it stop, and it won't stop by itself.

Comment: I expected the outside setInterval to break it.

Comment: @Volune, I should have used clearInterval.

Comment: So that's the point that went wrong in your code. You can find solutions to this problem in the answers. To explain a little bit more: Inside the first call to ```count```, the first timer created by the call of ```setInterval``` has no way to be known inside the second call of ```count```, and then cannot be canceled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that each call is in its own new object and you get multiple instances of itself fighting ever 10 seconds.

Using your approach using date objects here is a possible re-write:

```
var tmr = null;
var time;

function bigInterval() {
    clearInterval(tmr);
    time = (new Date()).valueOf() + (10 * 1000);
    smallInterval();
    tmr = setInterval(smallInterval, 500);
}

function smallInterval() {
    var cur = (new Date()).valueOf();
    var seconds_left = parseInt((time - cur) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = seconds_left + " seconds";
}

bigInterval();
setInterval(bigInterval, 10*1000);
```

In the above code I've updated the small timer to be 500ms instead of 1000ms as it won't exactly line up with the system clock at 1000 and you get visual jumps in the numbers.

If exact timing isn't 100% important then here is a possible shorter method:

```
var t = 10;

setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = t + " seconds";
    t--;
    if (t <= 0) {
        t = 10;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It's also important to note that inactive tabs, in Firefox (and maybe in Chrome, not sure about IE), are capped at executing no more than once every 1000ms. So, if your user tabs away to another page, or puts this page in the background, your counter will automatically be throttled by the browser itself.

Comment: Also, I still recommend taking the `document.getElementById` call out of the loop. Unless there's a valid reason the object will disappear between timer executions, it makes no sense to grab a new reference to the object every time, and can create its own minuscule delays.

Comment: I agree about caching the document.getElementById. It was left that way as a quick way to demonstrate the timer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on, here. You're not specific why you have to set another interval inside your loop, but there are a lot easier ways to accomplish what you're going for. Another approach follows:

HTML:

```
<!-- string concatenation is expensive in any language. 
     Only update what has to change to optimize -->
<h1 id='countdown'><span id="ct"></span> seconds </h1>
```

JS:

```
// For one thing, grabbing a new reference to the 
// dom object each interval is wasteful, and could interfere with
// timing, so get it outside your timer, and store it in a var scoped
// appropriately.
var ct = document.getElementById("ct");
// set your start
var ctStart = 10;
// set your counter to the start
var ctDown = ctStart;

var count = function() {
    // decrement your counter
    ctDown = ctDown - 1;
    // update the DOM
    ct.innerHTML = ctDown;
    // if you get to 0, reset your counter
    if(ctDown == 0) { ctDown = ctStart; }
};

// save a reference to the interval, in case you need to cancel it
// Also, you only need to include a reference to the function you're
// trying to call, here. You don't need to wrap it in an anonymous function
var timer = window.setInterval(count, 1000);
```

My jsFiddle available for tinkering, here: http://jsfiddle.net/21d7rf6s/

Comment: one of my loops was for renewing time every second, - and another for restarting function every 10 seconds.

Comment: A detailed explanation of browser timers, if you're concerned about exactness: http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval
My code above does not go to the lengths described in that article, so it mainly depends on how specific you need your timer to be, I think.